# Debugging nested STL Containers in KDevelop

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, kdevelop

in KDevelop, when I debug a vector, I can see its content. This is the result of

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
```

[image]

but debugging a vector< vector < int > > doesn't show its content. This is the result of

```
vector< vector < int > > v = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
```

[image]

How can I debug nested STL containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a known bug in KDevelop](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=330734) which was fixed in version [4.7.0](https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/kdevelop/kdevelop/repository/changes/debuggers/gdb/gdbvariable.cpp?rev=v4.7.0).